# GPG Symmetric - Database

Tags: shell, gnupg, encryption-symmetric

I am a beginner in GNU PGP security stuff. I am trying to learn a few things.

For example, if I take the Symmetric key for a particular file `blah`

```
gpg --symmetric --no-use-agent "$blah"
```

it now tells me to enter  `secret key/password`. After entering that , it generates a file named `blah.gpg`.

But, is there a place where gpg stores all the keys? If yes, where , can I access the DB it via `sqlite3` and can be ported to the server end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric keys are not stored. You give them and the program applies and forgets them. keys for asymmetric ciphers are stored in ~/.gnupg/ by default. And I don't think they are stored using sqlite3.